# iphone sdk 4.1 Is it possible for a background application to get cellular call events?

Tags: iphone-sdk-4.1

I am trying to use CTCallCenter in a background application to receive CTCallCenter events. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes and No.... It's complicated.

If your application is running a background task, then yes you will get events in the background.   The problem is that background task will timeout in ten minutes (currently).  So you can only get call events for the first ten minutes after going into the background....